# Inequality between two entropy functions

Tags: inequality, entropy

I have two functions whose functional forms are of Shannon entropy type. The functions are:

$$f_1 = x \log x + (1-x)\log (1-x)+y \log y + (1-y)\log (1-y)$$
and
$$f_2 = xy \log (xy) + (1-xy)\log (1-xy)$$
Here both $x,y$ are less than 1. I want to know whether $f_2>f_1$ or $f_1>f_2$ ? Is there any inequality which says that. I tried some analytical calculation but couldn't succeed. Can anyone suggest anything ?

Comment: This belongs on math.se, but no, neither are always larger than the other, neither the Real, not the Complex parts.

Comment: @Feyre You can flag for migration even if you can't vote to close.  Actually $f_2$ is always larger, notice that this is about the $0 < x, y < 1$ case.  From an information theory viewpoint, that's because in $f_2$ he doesn't consider the case when only one of the two events happens.  For two events with binary outcomes there's 4 joint outcomes in total.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did, but you're right, I mistook a `-` for a `+` in transcribing the code.